# Tkinter and GUI refresh

Tags: python, tkinter

The current code displays a GUI with the listbox after all 3 elements have been added to the list. Is it possible to do it more interactively i.e. the GUI and the listbox are displayed immediately after the program starts, then every 1s a new element is added to the listbox? I would like to have a solution without parallelism, threads and synchronisation.

```python
from Tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

for i in range(0,3):
    #Time consuming task which results are placed sequentially in the listbox
    time.sleep(1)
    listbox.insert(END,"Task "+str(i)+" completed")
    #GUI update needed here
    #.....???

mainloop()
```

I tried to use *after* method like in the second listing, however the listbox is still not displayed until all the items are added to it.

```python
from Tkinter import *
import time

def time_consuming_task():
    for i in range(0,3):
        time.sleep(1)
        listbox.insert(END,"Task "+str(i)+" completed")


master = Tk()
listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()
master.after(100,time_consuming_task)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `after()` as below:

```py
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

def time_consuming_task(n=0):
    if n < 3:
        listbox.insert(tk.END, 'Task {0} completed'.format(n))
        master.after(1000, time_consuming_task, n+1)

master.after(1000, time_consuming_task)
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep calling the `after` method to set up a chain of calls:

```py
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def time_consuming_task():
    listbox.insert(END, "Task " + str(time_consuming_task.i) + " completed")
    time_consuming_task.i += 1
    if time_consuming_task.i < 3:
        master.after(1000, time_consuming_task)       

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()

time_consuming_task.i = 0
time_consuming_task()
mainloop()
```

Also it is vital that you don't call `sleep()` in your code, otherwise tkinter will hang for that time.